# Question about partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x, y) = x^2 + g(y)$. Is the partial derivative subject to $x$ now $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$? Since $y$ is considered to be constant, I am guessing $g(y)$ will be always constant too. However, my mathematical knowledge being very limited, I wanted to make sure. If it's true, how could I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, and your argument is sound. To prove it even more rigorously, just write up the definition:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^2+g(y)-(x^2+g(y))}{h}$$
and notice how the $g(y)$ terms cancel out, leaving just the definition of the ordinary derivative of $x^2$.